# copy text layer in photoshop without text changes

Tags: photoshop

I have some text in Photoshop, which I want to use in the web page as image, to save the special font, which is not supported by the browser.
When I try to copy the text layer to a new document in Photoshop, so that I can save it as a separate image file, the text appears very bold, different from the text in the original file.

p.s.: I copy the text layer using: select layer - right click - duplicate layer - to new document;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just do the following

1. Select the text layer
2. Make a selection with the selection tool around your text
3. copy (CTRL + C)
4. open a new document (width and height should already be filled with exactly your selection)
5. paste you copy
6. save

Answer (score 0):

You see below the link.
http://www.ampsoft.net/webdesign-l/WindowsMacFonts.html

Some text i mean titles use image but SEO purpose strictly want text only(like heading tags)